# fopen returns empty content for php://stdin

Tags: php, nginx, fpm

I am unable to get fopen to read content stream in PHP. There is no error thrown, the content is always empty string.

Here is my code:

```
$contents='';
$handle = fopen("php://stdin", "r") or error_log('got some error');

while (!feof($handle)) {
    $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);
error_log($contents);
```

Then from Postman I send POST request at my server url like

POST http://myserverurl/index.php

I do send post data on above request, I have tried form-encoded, binary and raw too.

But error_log logs empty string to the log file, which means that fopen did actually work but it got empty content.

I have checked php.ini settings as well and allow_url_fopen setting is true as well.

I am testing this on nginx with PHP7.1-fpm. I recently switched from Apache and PHP 5.6 to nginx and php7.1-fpm and it stopped working.

It was totally working fine with Apache and PHP5.6.

What is wrong here?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: In my case it needed allow_url_include = On  , was Off by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably some misunderstanding in the default streams of PHP.

- If you're running the PHP script as a command, the CLI interface would give you [php://stdin](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php).
- If you're running the PHP script in a web server / cgi / php-fpm environment, there is no `php://stdin` at all. You'll be getting [php://input](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input) stream (for the POST body) instead.

Reference: [Supported Protocol and Wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input)

Comment: Yes actually I am running this as CLI command. Basically I have setup a hook on postfix to pipe the incoming email to php script so that whenever I receive an email then a php script executes. In CLI script when I used php://stdin then content is empty. 
Thanks for above clarificition about that though. But can you please tell when php://stdin has empty content when CLI script tries to access the content stream with php://stdin?

Same code worked with apache but stopped working after server OS upgrade

Comment: What OS are you using? Is it possible to be a OS / Postfix upgrade issue?

Comment: Current OS setup is Ubuntu 16.04 with Nginx and PHP7.1-FPM...
Earlier setup was Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache2 and PHP 5.6...

I just did 'do-release-upgrade' on OS meaning I did not install postfix again and older configuration worked for my postfix, just this email hook thing is not working

Comment: What does `echo "hello world" | php your-script.php` return?

Comment: Did "hello world" | php your-script.php and it does log content to log file which confirms that it is postfix issue. Thanks a lot for your help. Do you have any idea what can be wrong with postfix not sending content to script?
I can post my main.cf configuration if you say.

Comment: Sorry. Not familiar with Postfix :-P

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your help. At least you helped me point in right direction for resolution of issue. I can read about that what can be wrong with postfix.